# Jquery POST Response security

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i use jquery to submit login form with the following code :

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST', 
url: 'register_process.php', 
data:$('#login').serialize(), 
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#login_process').html("<img src='img/sloader.gif' />");
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#login_process').html(response);
        $("#navbar").load(location.href + " #navbar");
        alert(response);
        if(response="ok") {
            $(location).attr('href',"log.php"); 
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

and this is my php code :

```
`if($userlogin=='ok') {
   print 'ok';
} else
   print 'not ok';`
```

but I think that im not doing the proper thing, is there any other way to catch jquery post response with  specific conditions from  php?

thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean a better response/test than printing ok/not ok and testing against that?

Comment: @Yassuki define 'proper' to us. as is, its hard to identify where you are trying to get to

Comment: yes, and better way than only catch string "ok"

Comment: you mean proper authentication checking then? If so we'll need to know what type of authentication you are intending to use.

Comment: @hubson proper mean "how smart guys with php do this thing correctly..", because i think that im doing wrong with my code